# SwiftUI - How to handle drop event outside of my View

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, drag-and-drop, lazyvgrid

I'm implementing drag & drop in LazyVGrid. I'd like to call some function when drop happens outside of my `View`. How can I get the callback?

Here is my code:

```
var body: some View {
    LazyVGrid(columns: ...) {
        ForEach(...) { item in
            createItem(...)
                .onDrop(of: [.text], delegate: DropRelocateDelegate(didFinishDragging: {
                    draggingItem = nil
                    viewModel.didFinishDragging()
                }))
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm making some changes when drop happens. However this is only called when drop happens inside a grid. I'd like to make the exact same changes when drop happens outside of the `View`.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way would be to nest your [`LazyVGrid`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/lazyvgrid) in a [`ZStack`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/zstack) with a [`Rectangle()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/rectangle/). The `Rectangle()` should fill the screen. You can then set the `ZStack` item alignment to [`top`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/alignment/top) or whatever else you like.

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            Rectangle().foregroundColor(.clear)
            LazyVGrid(columns: ...) {
                ForEach(...) { item in
                    createItem(...)
                        .onDrop(of: [.text], delegate: DropRelocateDelegate(didFinishDragging: {
                            draggingItem = nil
                            viewModel.didFinishDragging()
                        }))
                }
            }
        }
        .onDrop(of: [.text], delegate: DropRelocateDelegate(didFinishDragging: {
            draggingItem = nil
            viewModel.didFinishDragging()
        }))
    }
}
```

Now in some cases, there may not be a need for putting `onDrop()` on the `LazyVGrid` items. Adding it to the `ZStack` should affect the entire screen. However, I included it just in case.

Comment: The situation is more complex. My SwiftUI View is wrapped into a UIKit View (UIHostingController) and is placed on a screen alongside other UIKit Views (UIView).

Comment: @LevanKaranadze Ah ok I see. Would it be possible to pass the frame of the `UIHostingController` to this `View`? You could then set the  `ZStack`'s frame to the `UIHostingController`'s frame. I know that's a pretty simple answer as well. If anything maybe it'll get an idea started...

Comment: Hmm, actually I can but it will require to modify whole layout and will also make it harder to use this View in other places.

Comment: @LevanKaranadze Yeah I thought so. Take a look at this [tutorial](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-control-the-tappable-area-of-a-view-using-contentshape) from HackingWithSwift. You could also try nesting your `LazyVGrid` in a `GeometryReader`. It's hard to say if it'll work since I cannot see your complete setup, but it's worth a try!